# How to extract Name from id,which a Lookup field catches?

Tags: trigger, lookup

I have Lookup field value of object A and used trigger to display the same field value in object B.If I use a field of type text,then I can see ID.if I use a field of type Lookup,then I can see the same name it hold in object A.
   Is it possible to get Name in the lookup field of object A into a field of type text as Name instead of Id in object B? how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  a formula field to show the name of the lookup field. Set the type of formula field to `text`

Comment: Thanks for reply,Saket Joshi.I tried it,but it is showing me ID instead of name.Please help me with a better solution.

Comment: It worked for me.The mistake which I have done is: I entered field name as OwnerID instead of Owner.Name.